# How to check for NaN in any data structure in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to check for NaN in any arbitrary data structure in python?

Essentially, I would like a function, `def containsNan(d)` which would return `True` for any arbitrary standard python data structure `d`, if there is any `NaN` inside `d`.

I looked into flattening `d`, before doing some kind of `apply()`, with `math.isnan()` but there doesn't appear to be a general flatten that works on any `d`.

Any ideas on what approach I should try?

Comment: Perhaps look into recursion to walk through an object and its members, applying your `isnan()` test. If you find one, step out of the recursion early (no need to check everything).

Comment: @AlexReynolds Great idea - I will google for an implementation - thx.

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy. Try using the pandas module for this job. It has a variety of functions for dealing with NaNs.

Check for null values:

```
df.isnull().values.any()
```

Count the number of null values:

`df.isnull().sum().sum()`

Note: This works in a pandas data frame. So if you want to work with a list or something convert it before doing this

Comment: Hi was there any shortcomings in my answer that I could fix?